# How to make IIS Default Webpage

Tags: iis-7

I just install IIS7 in my new server and try to create a few applications in it. I am calling this application aaa, xxx, and yyy. But instead calling it in browser in full site (http://172.0.0.1/aaa or http://172.0.0.1/xxx or http://172.0.0.1/yyyy) is it possible to make one it to be default? so if i call it http://172.0.0.1 it will automatically open xxx application. Right now if I call it by IP or hostname it will open iis default page. Please let me know if you know how to redirect it.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you're looking for is **Site Bindings**. You can find it in IIS Manager in the *Actions* menu (it appears when you select a site).

[image: Actions menu]

If you click the **Default Web Site** in your server and open the bindings you should see a configuration like this:

[image: Binding settings]

This specific setting states that any requisition to your server of type http to the port 80 (the default port for http) to any IP address configured on this server should be answered with this specific site.

Answering your question: Remove this binding configuration from your **Default Web Site** (or stop the site if you prefer) and configure your site xxx with the bindings above. Not the best configuration for a production server though. Before you configure your production environment I suggest you read [Understanding IIS Bindings, Websites, Virtual Directories, and lastly Application Pools](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/). By the way, the other sites should have different ports if you intend to use the same IP or hostname to call them. The trick is that you mustn't have the same combination of **Type, Host Name, Port, IP Address** for different sites.